# Error while integrating vockal kit lib in IPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, speech-to-text

I'm developing an app where I want to convert speech to text. For this I'm integrating VocalKit third party lib  from   https://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit. When I'm including the code and compiling its giving me error.I hav made all the necessary changes and imported the framework.

Here is my code

```
 (void) recognizedTextNotification:(NSNotification*)notification  {
    NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo]; NSString *phrase =
    [dict objectForKey:VKRecognizedPhraseNotificationTextKey];
    [patientId setText:phrase];  }
```

I'm getting following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:  
"_VKRecognizedPhraseNotificationTextKey", referenced from:
      -[ViewController recognizedTextNotification:] in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Comment: Use Openears instead, it's essentially the same pocketsphinx code as vocalkit, but way better supported.

Comment: But in open ears we hav to add pre defined words. I'm making an app where user can speak anything and that has to be converted in to text

Comment: with VocalKit you also need a language model or the grammar

Comment: Please can you tell how can I implement that'

Comment: I told you use OpenEars and create a language model that fits your application. For more details see OpenEars documentation.

Comment: But why m I getting this error